# PCIe integration with ePRosima FastDDS layer of ROS2 humble as custom transport

Tags: ros2, pci-e, data-distribution-service

I'm working on a project that involves establishing communication between two ROS2 Humble-supported embedded Linux boards using a PCI Express channel. I have access to the necessary PCIe APIs for board-level communication.

I'm aiming to leverage the eprosima Fast DDS middleware as the DDS vendor due to its well-documented source code for transport layer extensions. My goal is to create a custom transport layer for PCIe that sits on top of Fast DDS transport layer.

I'm reaching out to the community to seek suggestions and insights on the best approach for implementing this custom PCIe transport layer.

Fast DDS provides transport and descriptor interface headers that are used to implement protocols like UDP, TCP, and SHM. here I am trying to add the specific PCIe interfaces. facing challenges to implement the code flow by referring specification documents of DDS and RTPS (OMG specification) and the eProsima Fast DDS documentation.
[https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastdds/transport/transport.html]